# Can not connect to Linux instance using SSH through Putty

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, ping, timeout, putty

Just signed up for GCP account and created a Linux VM on GCP (SUSE) and having issues to connect via SSH through Putty.
Also tried through CMD prompt on Windows 10 and get the same issue. Followed up all the steps to generate ssh keys and uploaded public key on GCP (also, I can see the key in .ssh directory).
Firewall is set to enable all hosts and ports to connect.
I am able to ping the External IP but when trying to ssh into the VM there is no response and ends in timeout.
ssh -i pathtoKeyfile user@External_IP
ssh: connect to host xx.xx.xx.xx port 22: Connection timed out

Please help with any suggestion on similar issues.

Comment: I don't know GCP, but I would check port 22 is open in any GCP / instance firewall first, and check the SSH daemon is running - which it probably is.

Comment: You list the steps but no details. Connection Timed Out typically means you have not created an ingress rule allowing SSH or you are connecting to the wrong IP address, .... Edit your question with details on what you have configured.

Comment: Firewall is configured as below (assumed to allow all ports/IP to connect to):

Type          Targets Filters Protocols / ports Action Priority Network Logs Hit count 
allow-ssh-from-putty Ingress Apply to all  IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 all Allow 1000 default On